# Batch file to compare text files and write that textfile names to mismatch.txt

Tags: batch-file

i have 400 text files, all text file has numeric values only.

folder1\car1.txt,car2.txt and upto car400.txt

folder2\car1.txt,car2.txt ....car400.txt

i want to compare all these files like folder1\car1.txt with folder2\car1.txt and folder1\400.txt with folder2\400.txt  and if they are not matching i want the batch to write those file names to mismatch.txt

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
>mismatch.txt (
  for %%F in (folder1\*.txt) do >nul 2>&1 fc "%%F" "folder2\%%~nxF"||echo %%~nxF
)
```

Comment: dbenham you are great..thank you so much it worked like wat i wanted.you are really great.